# Is there a NodeJS equivalent to Powershell's WebSession for multiple http requests

Tags: node.js, http, cookies, session-cookies

Is there a Node.js equivalent to using Powershell's Invoke-WebRequest with WebSession parameters to persist state over multiple calls?

I am writing a Node application that makes multiple http calls to authenticate to a site and then download a file. The site is using ASP.NET session cookies in a way that I can't decipher how to make properly-authenticated calls by manually managing cookies on my requests. I'm currently using node-fetch to make requests, but am not tied to a particular package.

I have a working mockup in Powershell, using Invoke-WebRequest and its WebSession parameter:

```
$loginURI = "$($baseURI)/Account/Login"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $loginuri -Method Get -SessionVariable session
$requestBody = @{
    'Email' = "$($username)"
    'Password' = "$($password)"
}
$loginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $loginURI -Method Post -Body $requestBody -WebSession $session 

$downloadResult = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadBase -Method Get -WebSession $session -OutFile $outputFilePath
```

(assuming the URIs and credentials are defined)

EDIT to include non-working Node attempt:

```
const baseUri = 'https://mtgmelee.com/';

fetch(baseUri, {encoding: null, method: 'GET'})
    .then(res => 
    {
        var rvt = res.headers.raw()['set-cookie'].find(c => c.startsWith('__RequestVerificationToken'));
        var session = res.headers.raw()['set-cookie'].find(c => c.startsWith('ASP.NET_SessionId'));
        nodecg.log.info(session);
        nodecg.log.info(rvt);
    });
```

The RequestVerificationToken cookie will be parsed and logged, but the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie will not be. When making subsequent requests in the browser, dev tools show both cookies attached to the next request.

Is there a Node equivalent to managing session in this way?

Comment: You allready mention the solution: cookies. Just handle them properly while making requests. Whats the problem? Your question need more details.

Comment: @Marc The problem is that I can't get the cookies right, and WebSession can. Looking at the cookies on the request/response objects in my Node app and comparing them to the cookies on requests/responses in a browser, I'm missing the "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie - I can't see it on any responses.

Comment: Cookies are mentioned in [`node-fetch`'s docs here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#extract-set-cookie-header), most modern libraries have ways documented, e.g. [`got` docs it here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/main/documentation/2-options.md#cookiejar)

Comment: @PaulS. - I'm already able to retrieve a cookie from a response and set it on the next request using node-fetch. What I can't do is find the particular set of cookies and options to make my request succeed - and WebSession can do that, so clearly there's something I'm missing

Comment: @JRandomHacker Without more info/examples you are unlikely to get a solution. Try outputting the full requests to log files / perform the same requests in a browser where you can inspect the network tab, and compare the successful attempt to the failed attempt -- you're likely missing an encoding step, or if there are no other differences it could even be something like the server has a useragent check which rejects default nodejs user agents

Comment: I've determined what may be the issue, and now I can either edit my question substantially, or ask a different question. The cookie I need is set as HttpOnly, which seems to imply that it's explicitly designed to prevent me from doing the thing I want to do. My question is now: how does Invoke-WebRequest do it?

Comment: Show us your actual `node-fetch()` code.  You are perhaps doing something wrong with the request.  `httpOnly` is a browser safeguard and should not apply to your own programmatic client if you are doing things correctly.

Comment: Also, if you can provide a specifi URL request, parameters required and cookies involved, we can actually try your code, see the issue and hopefully provide a solution.  What you're trying to get to is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your real code so we have the best chance of diagnosing and helping rather than just trying to guess which is what everyone has been doing so far.

Comment: And, if you need to retain cookies between requests, then you will want some sort of "cookieJar" kind of functionality you can use with `node-fetch()` whose job it is to retain cookies for a particular domain and send them with future requests.

Comment: I've edited the main question to include my non-working node code.

Comment: Well, when I do you `fetch()` to the host you show, I don't see any cookie come back that starts with `ASP.NET_SessionId`.  Even if I go to the browser and look, I don't see that cookie.  Even if I register an account on the site and then look, I don't see that cookie.

Comment: There is a cookie named `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie`, but that's not the one your code looks for.

Comment: Rather than knowing the name of the cookie you need (which could be changed out of your control, making your code fragile) hand over the responsibility of managing all cookies to a [cookiejar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tough-cookie#cookiejar), as jfriend00 suggests